# Randomise X most recent wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got the following code which will display 4 random posts from the defined category. However, that's a little too random, I need it to display the 4 most recent, and then randomise them in particular each time the page is refreshed.

Otherwise I just end up getting articles which could date back over 2 years ago appear on the homepage.

```
<div class="article-block-v1">
<?php
//get terms (category ids 11,2,33,34), then display one post in each term
$taxonomy = 'category';//  e.g. post_tag, category
$param_type = 'category__in'; //  e.g. tag__in, category__in
$term_args=array(
  'include' => '1459',
);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);

if ($terms) {
  foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $args=array(
      "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
      'orderby' =>  'rand',
      );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    $i = 1;

    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ($i == 1): ?>

    <div class="article-block-v1">

    <div class="category-label-large category-news-analysis">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php echo $term->name; ?></p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="view2 third-effect">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="mask">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="info" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="homepagewhitebg">
        <li><h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5></li>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <?php else: ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a></li>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        $i++;
          endwhile;
          echo '</ul>';
        }
      }
    }
    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

**Demo 1 (4 Most Recent) - Regular without random orderby**
Article #1001
Article #1002
Article #1003
Article #1004

**Demo 2 (4 Most Recent - But with order by random on those 4)**
Article #1003
Article #1001
Article #1004
Article #1002

---

**UPDATE**
I'm also trying this now, however it's not taking into account the category I've defined, nor is it randomising across the 4 displayed:

```
<div class="article-block-v1">

<?php
$number = "4";
$posts = "SELECT * from $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='post' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $number";
$postX = array();
$postresult = mysql_query($posts) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($postresult)) {
$postX[] = $row[0];
}
$ids = shuffle($postX);
$ids = implode(',', $postX);
echo $ids;

?>
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=> $number,
    'post__in' => explode(',', $ids),
    'include' => '1451',
    'orderby' => 'rand'
  );
query_posts($args);
 ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You first need to write a query to return the 4 most recent posts. Your code above isn't really relevant to the question.

Comment: Ok yeah I've added my attempt so far, working on it but any suggestions welcome as it's still not quite there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php). You're going to want to get the 4 most recent posts (in order) before shuffling them. Quite simply, you could do something like the following:

```
// Get the 4 most recent posts
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 4 );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

// Shuffle them
shuffle($recent_posts)

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    // Do something with the $recent post
}
```

You may need to pass additional `$args` to the function, for your specific constraints.

Comment: Ok yeah think it's coming through, just one last basic thing I hope, how now would I retrieve the titles, thumbnail etc within the foreach loop.

I've tried: **echo $recent->post_title;** but with no luck. No output.

Comment: By default, [wp_get_recent_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) returns arrays. You can access the title, for example, by `$recent["post_title"]`. Check out the docs for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

Comment: Ah almost got everything now, thank you. One thing was, I suppose I would need to use: **get_the_category** function, but how might I be able to then call the category whilst in the $recent_posts loop which is using **wp_get_recent_posts**?

Comment: That's kind of a different question, but you'd pass the post ID into `get_the_category()`...for example: `echo get_the_category( $recent['ID'] );`. Please select my answer to close up this question, and feel free to ask another if you have additional questions.